# Why is the "this" keyword is not referring to the state I'd set?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I began studying JavaScript yesterday, today I was at the object and functions topic.

I'd already made this work, but I'm really in doubt why in the dog1 object, if I use the this keyword I just get "undefined" return on the log.

I'd already search this here and on google, but without luck. I'm not looking for a code to solve this, just to understand why in the second case the "this" is not working.

```js
 var dog0 = {
     Name: "Bob",
     color: "Golden",
     breed: "Labrador",
     dogcard1: function() {
        return  "Hi, this is " + this.Name + ", a " + this.color + " " + this.breed ;
     }
 };

 console.log(dog0.dogcard1());


function dogcard(a, b, c) {
    return  "Hi, this is " + a + ", a " + b + " " + c ;
 }

var dog1 = new Object();
dog1.Name = "Suzy";
dog1.color = "black";
dog1.breed = "Bulldog";
dog1.presentation = dogcard(this.Name, dog1.color, dog1.breed);
console.log(dog1.presentation);
```

Comment: Is this java???

Comment: You're talking about JavaScript here.  Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Comment: because `this` isn't referring to what you think it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: It's working correctly, but not how you expect.  Note the distinction.

Comment: @Cam  I'm not even sure this is a dupe, `this` in Javascript can be confusing, but in this instance it's not even a JS oddity,.  He's calling `this` not even inside a function..  So what else could the OP think `this` is.. ?

Comment: Hey Keith, I think you're right -- this is not a duplicate of that question, for the reasons you specified. Retracted vote to close.

Comment: @Keith So the keyword wouldn't refer  to the state Name if it's not in a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting `undefined` back is because JavaScript has no earthly clue where `Name` came from.

In JavaScript, you can rely on three scopes:

- Block scope (for if statements, object declarations and loops),
- Function scope, and
- Global scope (where everything will be hoisted into if not guarded by the other scopes).

If you invoke `this`, you'll probably see it attached to `Window`, which is effectively the global space.  You don't declare `Name` there, which makes perfect sense.

Inside of your `dog1` object, you have the scope you need to refer to the immediately enclosed object, so `this` applies.  I would *still* discourage that particular use, though - personal preference - and instead pass the values in so it's crystal clear where everything's coming from.

You *probably* meant to use `dog1` instead of `this` for that specific variable, so I'd encourage you to fix that typo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Makoto . It was not a typo, I did it to show that even inside the `dog1` object, the keyword would return undefined, so it'd apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in strict mode, if this was not defined by the execution context, it remains "undefined".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this